# Variable username inside url address in NGINX

Tags: nginx

I still struggling with making mystaticusername variable user name. I mean when I have particular username /statisusername/ backend working properly on nginx. But how can I make my configuration for more users? Means use instead mystaticusername some redirection where each username will know login to backend.

How can I change my nginx configuration?

```
server {
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    charset utf-8;

    index index.html index.php /index.php;

    location = / {
            rewrite ^ /index.php;
    }
    location / {
            rewrite ^([^\.]*)$ /$1.php;
            rewrite ^/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)$ /admin/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    }
    location /mystaticusername {
            try_files $uri/ /admin/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }
    location = /mystaticusername/options {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /admin/index.php?hotelname=$1&do=options;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you want in terms of what urls you want and where should they be point to?

Comment: Hey @alexeyten now when I write instead mystaticusername my realusername from database, all working like I want, So my url rewrites working when my url adress is like www.example.com/makromat/options but when I change username, redirections is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much context given, so I'm just guessin... but looks like you could condense your location directives to 3 statements.

This will default to index.php, but in the case of example.com/mystaticusername if would try that url and since it does not exist (guessing) it would serve up /admin/index.php?q=$uri&$args. This would also allow urls like exmaple.com/about to resolve. Just make certain to not allow users to create a username of 'about'

```
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /admin/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }
```

Not certain what your goal is, but this would get you example.com/mystaticusername/options to try serve up /admin/index.php?hotelname=$1&do=options

```
    location ~* ^/[a-zA-Z0-9]*/options$ {
            try_files $uri /admin/index.php?hotelname=$1&do=options;
    }
```

Leave php as-is

```
    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    }
```